# 500 - Internal server error in cake php website confing

Tags: php, cakephp

In cake php website source here my local pc that is confing properly but in live server problem as error 
**500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.**

How to solve this error in cakephp site config ?

Here my site details link http://www.florentserieye.com/

Comment: CRYSTAL_BALL_NOT_FOUND_ERR. How do you expect us to help without any details except for "there's a problem"? Check your error logs, for starters.

Comment: In app/Config/core.php set Configure::write('debug', 2);

Answer (score 1):

It means you have an internal error on your code. Try to locate the php error log file or the apache error log, they will have the information that tells you exactly where the error occurred.
Be sure to have php error logging enabled in `php.ini`.

Comment: how can check apache error log?

Comment: @maulik1987, [First result search in Google](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#errorlog)

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable **LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so** in appache config file(httpd.conf)

Comment: how can check LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2